# Android Database using Firebase

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to create a Student Attendance Management system in Android. I looked through the various options and find that implementing Firebase is the easy option to get connect to the database.

I want to ask that can I create the particular app using Firebase, which enables student and faculty to login. Faculty will mark the attendance and it will be reflected in student account in real-time with the notification that attendance is marked and similar type of functionality. Can I achieve it using Firebase? Please tell, So that I can start working out on the project or will find any other database method to implement it.

Sorry, If you find this question silly. I am beginner in Android.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely achieve this using firebase. Firebase has a lot of [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/) and libraries that makes it easier for you. You can also check out their [YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/Firebase).

Comment: [from review] explain a bit and provide doc please

Answer (score 0):

## Yes you can do it with Firebase Realtime database and Firebase Authentication.

1. You need to authenticate user because you did'nt want that anyone can check you data. You can use Email & Password authentication for students because its very easy and Admin Sdk for teachers and staff members.
2. You can structure data for each User according to your need.
3. You can upload it to firebase and then count the child that how many attendance are there.